# WI-FI is on but not connected to network

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which requires to check internet connection.When the WI-FI of the device is off it works perfectly fine but when I turn on the Wi-Fi but do not connect to the available network,it is force closing.What could be the problem?Please Help
boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable() {

```
  boolean connected = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm != null) {
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(ni != null){

                if(ni.isConnected())
                connected = true;
                else
                    connected=false;

           }

    }



    return connected;
```

}

Comment: I could not see the exception as it is not possible to test the app on emulator.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is you return true when your devise is connected to the WIFI but WIFI does not connect to the internet.You can solve this by executing  ping command programatically.

IDEA:

1) Check your are connect to the WIFI.

2)if you connect to the wifi ping to check network availability.

**Code:**

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context con,String url){

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) { 
        if(u!=null){
            return ping(url);
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ping method:

```
public static boolean ping(String u) { 
        try {
            URL url = new URL(u);
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(500); // Time is in Milliseconds to wait for ping response
            urlc.connect();
            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                Log.i(TAG, "* ping  with ResponseCode: "+urlc.getResponseCode());
                return true;
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "* Connection is too slow with ResponseCode: "+urlc.getResponseCode());
                return false;
            }
        }catch (MalformedURLException e1){
            Log.e(TAG,"Erroe in URL to ping"+e1);
            return false;
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Error in ping"+e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually my WI-FI connection requires credentials.If I put on my WI-FI and do not enter the credentials I will not be able to access internet.That is where it is giving exception.If I turn off wi-fi, my code is working perfectly but when I turn ON WI-FI and do not enter credentials,as I am not still connected to the internet,So it should return false but instead it is returning true only.Thank you for your response but I just want to give messege to the user that internet connectivity is not available.

Comment: As a programmer you should not worry about users network connectivity its up to users.Programmer must do is to handle notwork availability programatically above code will address that.according to above code if it is returning false you must give user notifications about  network availability.

Comment: But if I start the WI-FI and I dont have the connection with internet calling the url will give me an exception.What I want to do is if the device is not connected it should not call the url instead of giving exception.

Comment: while calling google page, white page is  appearing for milliseconds .How to resolve it